# WSO2: message broker, startup takes long (v 2.2.0)

Tags: message, wso2, messagebroker

We have installed WSO2 Message Broker, v2.2.0 on Suse 64 bit OS, single core. We have configured the master-datasources.xml to point to an Oracle database. The startup of the MB takes minutes, especially:

```
TID: [0] [MB] [2014-06-11 15:57:53,039]  INFO {org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ThriftServer} -  Listening for thrift clients... {org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ThriftServer}
TID: [0] [MB] [2014-06-11 15:57:53,219]  INFO {org.apache.cassandra.service.GCInspector} -  GC for MarkSweepCompact: 407 ms for 1 collections, 60663688 used; max is 1037959168 {org.apache.cassandra.service.GCInspector}
TID: [0] [MB] [2014-06-11 15:58:39,137]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.common.IServerAdmin,org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.ThrottlingAgent, {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent}
TID: [0] [MB] [2014-06-11 15:59:39,136]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.common.IServerAdmin,org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.ThrottlingAgent, {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent}
TID: [0] [MB] [2014-06-11 16:00:39,136]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.common.IServerAdmin,org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.ThrottlingAgent, {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent}
```

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: How about the memory on your node?

Comment: Seems this issue arise with node memory size. on production environment they recommend to set at least 2 GB memory

Comment: I changed the min mem and max mem to 2048M and permgen 512M, the startup takes still minutes.

Comment: AFIK, this can be occur due to OSGI Service did not start properly in the environment. can you please try with different OS ? I just checked with Ubuntu and it worked as expected

Comment: Changing OS is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

With Wso2 MB 220 we are getting these kind of errors when zookeeper/casandra server does not start properly.Ideally if clustering enabled zookeeper(Internal or External) server should be started properly before MB starts.
Further If you trying to run a MB cluster on a single machine and want to run two Zookeeper nodes there, Most probably you will be end up in these OSGI level errors.Please follow blog post on http://indikasampath.blogspot.com/2014/05/wso2-message-broker-cluster-setup-in.html for configuration details on WSO2 Message Broker cluster setup on a single machine